# Communicating between Delphi and Python

Tags: python, sockets, delphi, indy

I am building an application. Client side is written in Python but server side is written in Delphi. I am using indy in the Delphi side. I can connect to Delphi side but it doesn't write the message sent in the Python side to console. It just connects and disconnects when i terminate the process.

This is my Delphi code:

```
// .............................................................................
// *****************************************************************************
//   EVENT : onExecute()
//           ON EXECUTE THREAD CLIENT
// *****************************************************************************
procedure TBCPROServer.IdTCPServerExecute(AContext: TIdContext);
var
    msgF    romClient : ansistring;
    msgToClient   : ansistring;
begin
    msgFromClient := AContext.Connection.IOHandler.ReadString(1024);
    AContext.Connection.IOHandler.WriteLn(msgFromClient);
    Display('MSG :', msgFromClient);

    if bilgionay_fl=true then
                begin
                gelenbilgi:=msgfromclient;
                Display('Message:', msgFromClient);
                bilgionay_fl:=false;
                end;

if (gelenbilgi='start') then
   begin
     msgToClient :=params_frm.Label21.Caption;
     msgtoclient:=UTF8Encode(msgToClient);
     edit1.Text:= msgToClient;
     gonder_btnClick(nil);
   end;
end;
```

This is my Python code:

```
import time
import socket
from json import loads

HOST = "127.0.0.1"
PORT = 30000

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

s.connect((HOST, PORT))

s.sendall("start".encode())

while True:
    response = s.recv(1024)
    print(response)
```

I was expecting that to write the message that I send from the Python side. "start" in this case.